# Printing Strings in Java using replaceAll

Tags: java, regex, string

I am a beginner in Java. I don't understand how the below code is able to print all the characters in a string:-

```
System.out.println(yourString.replaceAll(".", "$0\n"));
```

I have tried reading the documentation on replaceAll and regex, still no clue.

Comment: It replaces each character with the same character followed by a newline. So `"HELLO"` becomes `"H\nE\nL\nL\nO\n"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`"."` is a regular expression which matches any single character. `$0` in the replacement string is a placeholder for the full match of the regex. `\n` is a line break.

Summarized, this snippet replaces each character with itself and adds a line break after the character.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for **replaceAll()** method is as follows:
**replaceAll(String regex, Stringreplacement)**  where:

**regex : regular expression
replacement : replacement sequence of characters**
so when you what to replace a character with \n basically every character will be printed in a different line. For example: **yourString = "Hello."** => 
output: Hello with every character on a different line

Answer (score 0):

If the String (as you specified) is `String yourString = "-";` so the result of `System.out.println(yourString.replaceAll(".", "$0\n"));` will be "-\n".

Actually, if you need to print all of the String characters why are you using `replaceAll`? Coz `System.out.println(yourString);` will do it perfectly.